# jQuery: assign array values to another set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    var i = 0; 
    var values = []; 
    var element = $('.source');
    element.each(function(i) { 
        values[i++] = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

I want to assign each array value above, as the individual `data-text` value on another set of list elements.  Something like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-text="arrayvalue1"></li>
  <li data-text="arrayvalue2"></li>
  <li data-text="arrayvalue3"></li>
</ul>
```

I don't understand how I would do this using jQuery.

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-text')`

Comment: `$(this).data('text')`

Comment: `$(this)[0].dataset['text']`

Comment: `.source` holds the elements we are pulling from. The html already exists for adding the `data-text` attributes, I just don't know how to pull from one array and inject the `data-text` attributes to another

Comment: @RobMyrick something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bkpgdvr3/)?

Comment: @empiric, yes I think this might be it.  Let me give it a shot.  Will you supply an answer I need to come back to this.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr()` to assign `data-text` values with values from another array. With `each()` loop you are iterating over all `li` elements in `ul` and adding values from `element` array starting from `0`, and you are also incrementing `i` by 1. So on second `li`, value of `i` will be 1 which is `arrayvalue2` etc...

```js
var element = ["arrayvalue1", "arrayvalue2", "arrayvalue3"]

var i = 0;
var values = $('ul li').each(function() {
  return $(this).attr('data-text', element[i++]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked: the `element[i++]` is what confused me for some reason.  Going to except this answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery's each(), try using this higher order function.
I don't have a complete picture of how your object looks but something like this should work:

```
element.forEach((el) => {
    el.dataset.text = referencedValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the "i" var, just do a push to the array of values. Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    var values = []; 
    var element = $('.source');
    element.each(function(i) {
        values.push($(this).data('text'));
    });
    console.log(values);
});
```

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/masqueradecircus/errq8cp7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have your source elements you can iterate through them and apply the `data` attribute referring to the `index of the element`:

```
var element = $('.source');
element.each(function(i) {
  $('#list > li').eq(i).attr('data-text', $(this).text());
  //or
  $('#list > li').eq(i).data('text', $(this).text());
});
```

Note: the difference of the two lines is:

`.attr()` will apply the value in the `dom` as an attribute to the element (visible in the html markup). The value can be retrieved with `.data()` or `.attr()`

The second one applies the value as an association to the element, which will not be reflected in the `dom`. This can only be retrieved with `.data()`

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5w9g5y6s/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use  $('.source li') and then you can use attr property in jquery to set the data-text attribute in another list.
Please find the sample below:
https://jsfiddle.net/vgade/km113ztL/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    var i = 0; 
    var values = []; 
    var element = $('.source li');
    element.each(function(i) { 
        $('#destination li')[i].attr("data-text",$(this).text());
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the point of `$($('#destination li')[i])` ? You are wrapping one jquery object on another

Comment: @empiric  Yes you are right $('#destination li')[i] this will work too.